# Apply a WCF attribute to all method in the service

Tags: c#, wcf, attributes

I have a custom attribute that I want to apply to each methods in my WCF service.

I proceed like this:

```
[MyAttribute]
void MyMethod()
{

}
```

The problem is that my service contains hundreds of methods and I don't want to write [Attribute] above all of them. Is there a way to apply the attribute to all my methods in my service?

Here's my attribute's signature:

```
//[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SendReceiveBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, /*IServiceBehavior,*/ IOperationBehavior
```

**EDIT after Aliostad's answer:**

I tried this:

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription desc, ServiceHostBase host)
{
    foreach (ChannelDispatcher cDispatcher in host.ChannelDispatchers)
    {
        foreach (EndpointDispatcher eDispatcher in cDispatcher.Endpoints)
        {
            foreach (DispatchOperation op in eDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations)
            {
                op.Invoker = new OperationInvoker(op.Invoker);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that:

```
public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
{
    foreach (ChannelDispatcher cDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
    {
        foreach (EndpointDispatcher eDispatcher in cDispatcher.Endpoints)
        {
            foreach (DispatchOperation op in eDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations)
            {
                op.Invoker = new OperationInvoker(op.Invoker);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it still don't work.

Comment: Depends on the specific attribute and, more importantly, on what code consumes it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [IServiceBehaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx) documentation, if you implement this interface and create an attribute and put it at the class level, it will be applied to all operations:

> Create a custom attribute that
>   implements IServiceBehavior and use it
>   to mark service classes that are to be
>   modified. When a ServiceHost object is
>   constructed, uses reflection to
>   discover the attributes on the service
>   type. If any attributes implement
>   IServiceBehavior, they are added to
>   the behaviors collection on
>   ServiceDescription.

---

### UPDATE

Instead of implementing `IOperationBehaviour`, add required behaviour in the `IServiceBehaviour` by **looping through all operations**:

```
foreach (EndpointDispatcher epDisp in chDisp.Endpoints)
{
    epDisp.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
    foreach (DispatchOperation op in epDisp.DispatchRuntime.Operations)
    {
        op.ParameterInspectors.Add(this); // JUST AS AN EXAMPLE 
    }                        
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right, I apply this attribute to the class and a part of it works, but the part that uses IOperationBehavior wont works if I don't apply it to all methods.

Comment: Thanks you, look in my edit to see what I've try.Makes perfect sense but it still don't work.

Comment: OK, let me get back to you after going home.

Answer (score 9):

The following should do the trick by using the service behavior to add the correct operation behavior which calls the invoker.

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior, IOperationBehavior
{
    #region IServiceBehavior Members
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase host)
    {
        foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            foreach (var operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            {
                operation.Behaviors.Add(this);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    #endregion

    #region IOperationBehavior Members
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.Invoker = new OperationInvoker(dispatchOperation.Invoker);
    }
    ...
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This sounded like a good answer to me, but it did not work either

Comment: I'm using this in production code today and it's working.  I'm not sure the issue you are having.  I'm not sure how to help further.  I double checked the code and nothing stands out a different than my production code.  Thanks.

Comment: @Aarron Stainback Mea Culpa! your code worked perfectly; i just forgot to remove the throw NotImplementedException() inserted by vs studio :).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define service behavior attribute, apply the attribute on service level. within the behavior, iterate through all methods defined in the contract and do all MyAttribute stuff.

Comment: it won't work unless you rewrite the way ServiceHost discover methods to be exposed in the service

Answer (score -1):

You can consider using AOP or post-build actions, in order to inject attributes into the compiled code.

Comment: How? The question is How?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati read docs for pretty much any AOP library for .net, like postSharp , aop.net etc. They have ability to be included in as post-build action. If you have particular question on that, feel free to ask it here on SO.

Answer (score -2):

Why you don't use T4 for generating repeatable codes?
It is better we use reflection in compile time than run time.

Logically service method is caller of a business method. So you can easily generate service methods with needed attributes by reading public methods of business class. It only needs giving attention when we implement business class.